# Teaxarea have inherent scope when i click on it is collapsing but don't let me to type my comment?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created already my code in [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zDHUjYLCi3wF4J1E4E6C?p=preview) . There is three directives which each of responsible to collapse somethings.
If you execute this code you will see there is 2 panel where if you click on address is collapsing. Also if you click on comment is collapsing too. However my problem came when i want to type some comment inside textarea then is going to collapse as well. This is not what i need. I would like to click on add comment [+], then is collapsing and start to type whatever i want. I define inherent scope in script.js. I am not sure how i can change my code in order to solve this problem. I will be thank you if any of you can help me.

This is add comment directive

```
.directive('addComment', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      templateUrl: "addComment.html",
      scope:true,
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.collapsed = false;
        $scope.collapseCom = function() {
          $scope.collapsed = true;
        }
        $scope.extendCom = function() {
          $scope.collapsed = false;
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

and this is my html.

```
<div ng-show="!collapsed" ng-click=collapseCom()>
  <h4>Add Comments: [+]<br /></h4>
  <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10">
      <textarea name="comment" ng-model="comment" class="form-control" rows="3" required></textarea>
        {{comment}}
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<div ng-show="collapsed" ng-click=extendCom()>
  <h4>Add Comments: [-]</h4>
</div>
```

To see all the details please click on following link.

Comment: there is no addcomment directive in your link

Comment: @user3906922 , what do you mean?  there is 'addComment' inside script,js.

Comment: in this plunker, there is only on directive (userInfoCard): http://plnkr.co/edit/zDHUjYLCi3wF4J1E4E6C?p=preview

Comment: @user3906922 sorry, it takes to update. i don't know why. but it is updated already.

Answer (score 0):

replace ng-click=collapseCom()
with ng-click="collapseCom()"

```
$scope.collapseCom = function() {
          $scope.collapsed = true;
        }
        $scope.extendCom = function() {
          $scope.collapsed = false;
        }
```

replace one method

```
$scope.collapseCom = function() {
      if($scope.collapsed){
         $scope.collapsed = false;
       }else{
        $scope.collapsed = true;
       }
}
```

This works like switch then, and should work fine